# How to deploy LLama on AWS Kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, large-language-model, llama

[image]

I'm stuck and getting many errors such as "waiting for Auto Scaling Group"

i've tried debugging via AWS but nothing seems to work - I got advised to change the plan and deployed on llama2 7b on a g5 endpoint

But you need to request the g5 virtual machine from AWS

Answer (score 0):

To use G5 instances (with NVIDIA A10G) in AWS, you'll need to request an increase in the [AWS Service Quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) item called `Running On-Demand G and VT instances`. Search for the "Service Quotas" page in the AWS console, click the group for Amazon EC2, and then enter the above item name in the quota search bar.

Note that this quota is in terms of vCPUs, not in terms of GPUs, so for example to run a single `g5.2xlarge`, you will need a quota of at least `8`. In my experience, a small quota increase like that should get automatically approved within about 30 minutes.

There are also some additional steps to properly configure Kubernetes to be able to use the attached GPU. I don't know if the Terraform provider helps with this, but I know that [eksctl does](https://eksctl.io/usage/gpu-support/). We have an example of using eksctl to provision an EKS cluster with GPUs in our [GPUs on Kubernetes](https://github.com/LogitsAI/beta/blob/main/docs/gpus.md) guide.

Once you have a Kubernetes cluster with GPUs, you'll also need to choose a way to actually deploy an LLM inference server onto it. You may be interested in using [Logits AI](https://github.com/LogitsAI/beta) for that, but our guide for GPUs on Kubernetes applies either way.